# Undefined is not a function & dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined-function

New to AngularJs I'm trying to train by building a single page Todo Application. The problem is, I'm having trouble loading a localStorage factory I'm trying to use for this. At the moment i'm stuck on the following error :

```
Undefined is not a function at routeconfig.resolve.store on app.js line 11.
```

Here's the code :

app.js

```
angular.module('TodoAngular', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';

    var routeConfig = {
        controller: 'TodoController' ,
        templareUrl: 'app/partials/TodoList.html',
        resolve: {
          store: function (todoAngularStorage) {
              // Récupère le module qui gère le localStorage
              return todoAngularStorage.then(function (module) {
                  module.get(); // Récupère les données
                  return module;
              });
          }
        }
    };

    $routeProvider
        .when('/todos', routeConfig)
        .otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: '/todos' 
        });
    }     
);
```

todoAngularStorage.js

```
angular.module('TodoAngular')
    .factory('todoAngularStorage', function ($http,$injector) {
        'use strict';

       return $injector.get('localStorage');
    })

    .factory('localStorage', function($q) {
        'use strict';

        var STORAGE_ID = 'todoAngularLocalStorage';

        var store = {
            todos: [],

            //récupérer depuis le local storage
            _getFromLocalStorage: function(){
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ID) || '[]');
            },

            //enregistrer dans le local storage
            _saveToLocalStorage: function (todos) {
                localstorage.setItem(STORAGE_ID, JSON.stringify(todos));
            },

            //supprimer un Todo
            delete: function (todo) {
                //instanciation de l'API Deferred
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                store.todos.splice(store.todos.indexOf(todo), 1);

                store._saveToLocalStorage(store.todos);
                deferred.resolve(store.todos);

                return deferred.promise;
            },

            //récupérer les todos
            get: function () {

                //instanciation de l'API Deferred
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                angular.copy(store._getFromLocalStorage(), store.todos);
                deferred.resolve(store.todos);

                return deferred.promise;

            },

            //ajouter un todo à la fin de la todo list  
            insert: function (todo) {

                //instanciation de l'API Deferred
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                store.todos.push(todo);

                store._saveToLocalStorage(store.todos);
                deferred.resolve(store.todos);

                return deferred.promise;

            }
      };

      return store;
});
```

I've been trying to debug it and it appears  that the problem comes from the 'module' passed in the function in the following line of my `app.js` file

```
return todoAngularStorage.then(function (module) {
```

I've been following this example (https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/angularjs) while building my app and I really don't see where's my mistake at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `localStorage` service factory is returning an object that doesn't have any property called `then`. You're then returning the same object from `todoAngularStorage` factory and trying to use `then` property of the returned value as a function, hence your error. It looks like you just wanted to do this:

```
return todoAngularStorage.get().then(function () {
    return todoAngularStorage;
});
```

---

*As a sidenote, you should be able to find this out by debugging (setting a breakpoint at the place where the problem is and looking at the variable values) and looking at your code (where did that value come from).*

Comment: Ty for answering, I'm trying to solve it with your advice. I'll get back to you if it helped.

Comment: I've looked your code over and updated my answer (I changed the "what I think you wanted to do" part).